# Visual Studio 2012 - new curios Errors in Xaml

Tags: image, xaml, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, uri

I use Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.0 (C#).
Now, I have added a Image in the Xaml:

```
<Image Source="/PPPos.Common.Images;component/Application/Pos.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
```

The Image Pos.jpg is included in the referenced Assembly PPPos.Common.Images.DLL as Resource.

Visual Studio 2012 gives me now the fallowing Exception in the ErrorList:

> Error 2   Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\PPPos.Common.Images;component\Application\Pos.jpg'.

But I can compile the Source without Problem and the Image will be shown when I run the Application.
This is also new with Visual Studio 2012 - there was no errormessage in the ErrorList with Visual Studio 2010.

Has someone an idea, what there could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me if you prefix the Source value with the "pack://application:,,,", in VS2012 and VS2013.
But I have reported this issue as a bug to the Visual Studio Team, because it is a new bad feature compare to VS2010, where you don't have to add this prefix. For behind compatibility the Visual Studio Team should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

after long searching I found the solution

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PPPos.Common.Images;component/Application/Pos.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
```

however I still do not know why this is the case in VS2013.
Any explanation will be appreciated.